# Pandas load time of day from csv as datetime

Tags: pandas

I have a csv thats formated like this:

```
start,end,name
12:00:00,14:00:00,thomas
14:00:00,16:00:00,hans
16:00:00,18:00:00,toby
18:00:00,20:00:00,ken
20:00:00,22:00:00,lisa
22:00:00,00:00:00,joe
```

How do I tell pandas to treat start and end like datetimes, even though they don't have any dates attacched while loading the csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read the csv you can `parse_dates`

```
df = pd.read_csv(files, parse_dates=['start','end'], 
        date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime(x).time())
```

Another way is use `converters`

```
 cov = dict(start = pd.to_timedelta, end = pd.to_timedelta)
 df = pd.read_csv(files, converters = cov)
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it!  The only thing is, of course, by using `pd.datetime.strptime` you revert back to strings.  Perhaps better to use `pd.to_datetime` with `format` specified?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify `parse_dates=['start', 'end']` in your call to `pd.read_csv`.

For example, if your data is in a file called 'data.csv', then this code will load `start` and `end` as datetime:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['start', 'end'])
```

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

contents = """start,end,name
12:00:00,14:00:00,thomas
14:00:00,16:00:00,hans
16:00:00,18:00:00,toby
18:00:00,20:00:00,ken
20:00:00,22:00:00,lisa
22:00:00,00:00:00,joe"""

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f_handle:
    f_handle.write(contents)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['start', 'end'])

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   start   6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   end     6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 2   name    6 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), object(1)
memory usage: 272.0+ bytes
```

And

```
print(df)
```

gives:

```
                start                 end    name
0 2020-04-01 12:00:00 2020-04-01 14:00:00  thomas
1 2020-04-01 14:00:00 2020-04-01 16:00:00    hans
2 2020-04-01 16:00:00 2020-04-01 18:00:00    toby
3 2020-04-01 18:00:00 2020-04-01 20:00:00     ken
4 2020-04-01 20:00:00 2020-04-01 22:00:00    lisa
5 2020-04-01 22:00:00 2020-04-01 00:00:00     joe
```

As you can see, `pandas` assumes the times are for today's date.